# Is there a way to declare a class that contains an unordered_set of itself?

Tags: c++

I would like to declare something like:

```
class A {
   std::unordered_set<A> set;
};
```

I know that I need a hash function for A, but I don't think that's the real problem.  The issue is that the constructor for unordered_set balks because A is an incomplete type.  A forward declaration of A doesn't fix that, but I'm not sure what else is possible.

As for a minimum reproducible example...

```
class A;

template <>
struct std::hash<A> {
  // declare, but don't define, because A isn't defined yet
  size_t operator()( const A& ) const;
};

class A {
   public:
   bool operator==( const A& ) const { return true; }

   std::unordered_set<A> set;
};

inline size_t std::hash<A>::operator()( const A& ) const { return 0; }
```

Is there any way to do this short of something like `unordered_set<A*>`?

With gcc 8.3.1 (C++14), I get:

```
/usr/include/c++/8/ext/aligned_buffer.h: In instantiation of struct __gnu_cxx::__aligned_buffer<A>:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/hashtable_policy.h:234:43:   required from struct std::__detail::_Hash_node_value_base<A>
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/hashtable_policy.h:265:12:   required from struct std::__detail::_Hash_node<A, true>
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/hashtable_policy.h:2038:49:   required from struct std::__detail::_Hashtable_alloc<std::allocator<std::__detail::_Hash_node<A, true> > >
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/hashtable.h:173:11:   required from class std::_Hashtable<A, A, std::allocator<A>, std::__detail::_Identity, std::equal_to<A>, std::hash<A>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<true, true, true> >
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/unordered_set.h:100:18:   required from class std::unordered_set<A>
/usr/include/c++/8/ext/aligned_buffer.h:91:28: error: invalid application of sizeof to incomplete type
 : std::aligned_storage<sizeof(_Tp), __alignof__(_Tp)>
```

Comment: I suspect the hash calculation will either be unstable / unreliable (depending on how you short circuit the calculation against recursion, and from what node is picked up as the starting node), or become a victim of the halting problem.

Comment: Derive class A from an abstract baseclass with pure virtual methods for what you want to access on A (an interface).  And make the set a set of unique_ptr's to the abstract baseclass.

Comment: *As for a minimum reproducible example...* - `<source>:8:33: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration`

Comment: Second attempt and... `<source>:15:15: error: no declaration matches 'size_t std::hash<A>::operator()(const A&)'`

Comment: Your [mre] produces [several errors](https://godbolt.org/z/Yddj5vfh4) but I don't suspect you are asking about any of them.

Comment: Fixed.  Sorry about that.

Comment: I don't understand the question. It compiles well if I add the missing #include. The [mcve] lacks of usage.

Comment: You also need `operator==` or a custom equality comparator.

Comment: It does not compile on g++ 8.3.1 (C++14).  I just edited the post to include the error message.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, true but adding it doesn't change the error message.

Comment: _"I just edited the post to include the error message"_  Your edit does not include the error message.  `In instantiation of ... required from ...` is not the error message.  The error probably begins with the word `error:`

Comment: Add `bool A::operator==(const A& other) const` and upgrade to gcc 12 or later. Problem solved :-)

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo, I'd love to, but I'm not free to change the version of gcc.  Is this a bug in gcc 8, or is this something changed in later versions of the standard?

Comment: @DrewDormann, last line of the error message got cut off.   It's included now.

Comment: Violates the [Axiom of Foundation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AxiomofFoundation.html).  Just saying.

Comment: @user1806566 Even if you _could_ upgrade, think about this: When you change the content of a `set` in an `A`, you would change the `A`s hash (I assume). That's not allowed unless you rip that `A` out of the `A` in which it's contained, but then you change that parent `A`s hash etc.

Comment: @Spencer Since two C++ sets can't contain the same object, I don't see what you're getting to. Also the code can be trivially made to work by switching to `std::vector`.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo  ```A``` represents a set, and and the object stores subsets of itself (essentially the Composite pattern from GoF).  The hash function would hash the contents of A, not of its contained subsets, so it wouldn't run into the problem you described.  The only reason I wouldn't use a vector is that I need to be able to quickly check if a particular subset exists.

Comment: So two `A`s could hash and compare equal even if their `set`s didn't? Ok, I suspect you'll want to make `set` `mutable` sooner or later. Inserts into `A`s inside other `A`s will be cumbersome otherwise.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It was just silliness.

Comment: If this class were more general-purpose, I would agree.  ```A``` is being used to represent a tree whose structure is fixed after construction, so I don't have to worry about the ```set``` changing.  ```A``` would have other data members which contained the data for that tree node, and the hash function would operate on those.

Comment: @user1806566 I see. Anyway, I played around a little with [an outline](https://godbolt.org/z/38M41b6xv) building on eerorikas answer.  So, you can make it work for in the general-purpose case too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to have a member container of self, the container type must support incomplete element type. This is because a type is incomplete in it's own member declarations. `std::unordered_set` does not support incomplete elements, so it isn't possible to have `std::unordered_set<A>`.

Indirection is a solution to many problems, as it is to this one. You can have `std::unordered_set<std::unique_ptr<A>>` for example.

Or if possible, you could define a custom set type, for example based on `std::vector` that keeps elements sorted. `std::vector` does allow incomplete element type.

Comment: *"std::unordered_set does not support incomplete elements"* Any reference for this? Newer libstdc++ seems to accept it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat [res.on.functions] disallows incomplete template arguments in general. Where they are allowed is by exception. list, forward_list and vector are the only containers which such exception. Violating the completeness requirement is UB, so the implementation is not required to diagnose it.